# Renaming files based on content of txt files

Tags: batch-file, text-files, file-rename

I have read all the similar questions and tried to use it to make a batch script, but unsuccessfully.

I have hundreds of txt files that all start like this: (without space between the lines)

```
SGCO Master Calibration Input Data, , , , , , , , , , , ,
  , , , , , , , , , , , , 
Date,09-Sep-2014, ,Eng:,Tom, , , , , , , ,
Serial Number,201659, ,Dwt. No.,2177 Cal Date 04.10.2013,,,,,,,,
Gauge Pressure Range, 10K, ,Dwt. Correctio Factor,1.00128,,,,,,,, 
Number of Temperatures,5, ,,,,,,,,,,
Number of Pressures,11, ,,,,,,,,,,
Calibration Temperature Unit, DEGC , ,,,,,,,,,, 
Calibration Pressure Unit, PSIG , ,,,,,,,,,,
```

(There aren't always the same amount of commas)
I want to use the following variables in my file name:
`10K` (after Range, )
`201659` (after Serial Number,)
`09-Sep-2014` (after Date,)

In this case the file name would be "`SG10K - 201659 - 09-Sep-2014.txt`"

Comment: But you have not asked a question....

Comment: How do I make a batch script that does this?

Comment: With `for` loops and `if` statements. What have you tried?

Comment: Are you restricted to batch script?

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM for all files do:
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
  REM get desired lines and set variables:
  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%i in (' findstr "^Date ^Serial Range," %%f') do set %%i=%%j
  REM construct filename:
  set "name=!Gauge Pressure Range: =SG! - !Serial Number! - !Date!.txt"
  echo Filename is: "!name!"
)
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. When I run this as a .bat file it lists what the file names would be, but it doesn't change a single file name.

Comment: your old filename is `%%f`, your new filename is `!name!`. So a simple `rename "%%f" "!name!` does the trick. Be sure, that the new names are ok, before you use `rename`, there is no "undo"